# What are some scenarios I would use MSFT Certificate Enrollment Web Services?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, kerberos

The Certificate Enrollment Policy Web Service and the Certificate Enrollment Web Service are made for [non domain connected machines](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831625.aspx#CEPConfig) to retrieve certificates of various kinds.

When setting this up, I have a few configuration options:

1. KeyBased Renewal (Authenticated with a prior certificate)
2. Username Password (sent over SSL?)
3. Kerberos

**Question**

- What are some sample scenarios where I would use each option?
- For option 1: do I need to have already issued certificates to devices?
- For option 3: Do I need to expose a Domain Controller to the internet, I remember reading an advisory saying that Kerberos shouldn't be used on the Internet
- What is the difference between the two services, and how are they used?

Comment: hmm found a reasonable use case for UserName password, but not the other two... 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/05/25/enabling-cep-and-ces-for-enrolling-non-domain-joined-computers-for-certificates.aspx